# Creating Visual Studio 2010 Extension

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to create an extension for Visual Studio 2010 that contains only a form which will be opened by keyboard shortcuts.

But i couldn't find any tutorial for this.

Which project that i had to create? VSIX Project or Visual Studio Package or Visual Studio Add-in.

I need your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a Visual Studio Package. Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164725.aspx) article, there's also a sample online about creating Menus and Commands that I could not find right now, but i know they are there :)

**Edit:** Since I got a downvote (?) I looked for the article I was talking about and found it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164725(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I will check and inform you. Thanks for your answer.